# "Italic" does not work in UILabel in Xcode -iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am trying to design a view as attached,

however, my label text is not "Italic" as I have already set in label attribute.

Tried to find solutions, but seems like all is programmatically adjustment.

Is there anything I miss out to config "Italic" in storyboard directly?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is known for having [bugs](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5117089870249984) when it comes to attributed text in the interface builder, so it is usually a better idea to select `Plain` instead of `Attributed` text in the utilities drawer, where you can still assign any custom font, family, style, and size you want.

[image: Italic Text]

Comment: but how to make underline text without attributed in storyboard.